# laravel supervizor queue MaxAttemptsExceededException

Tags: laravel, queue

I have a Laravel application and I use files with supervisor.

When I launch a job I have the following error after 60 seconds.

I have increased this delay everywhere but the timeout remains at 60 seconds.

Do you know how to increase the timeout of a job please?

I use the database connector (I also tried with redis) but it's the same

Thank you.

```
    class BuildAvailabilities implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $timeout = 600;

    protected $userId;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userId)
    {
        $this->onQueue('availabilities');

        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $availabilityService = app(AvailabilityBuilderService::class);
        $availabilityService->updateAvailabilities($this->userId);
    }

    /**
     * Get the middleware the job should pass through.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function middleware()
    {
        return [(new WithoutOverlapping($this->userId))->dontRelease()];
    }
}
```

Comment: nobody please ?

Answer (score 0):

In horizon.php under your's connection try to specify the `'timeout'` property to higher value and increase also the `'tries'` property of your connection. But the main problem for us is that our's jobs are just too unoptimized and runs too long.
Also you can also specify `public $maxExceptions = 3;` in job.
Tell me when you find a solution

And check this: https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/255